# Attribute value shown as undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my HTML and JavaScript code for getting attribute value. but I didn't get any output. The console said that 'Undefined'

```html
<div class="desktop">
  <h2 class="level3_sub" data-bookmark-flag="3">Lorem ipsum dolor</h2>
  <p class='normal_p'> dfsdfsdfsdfsdf</p>
  <p class='normal_p'> dfsdfsdfsdfsdf</p>
</div>

<div class="desktop">
  <h2 class="level3_sub" data-bookmark-flag="3">Lorem ipsum dolor</h2>
  <p class='normal_p'> dfsdfsdfsdfsdf</p>
  <p class='normal_p'> dfsdfsdfsdfsdf</p>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$( ".dekstop .normal_p" ).each(function( index ) {    
    var attId   = $(this).parent(".level3_sub").attr('data-bookmark-flag');
    onsole.log($(this).attr('data-bookmark-flag'));
    console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
});
```

Comment: onsole.log($(this).attr('data-bookmark-flag')); ???

Comment: Try `<div class='desktop'>`

Comment: sorry, that's a copying mistake. i changed that

Comment: @deepusankar I was waiting for that one, seeing as that's quite hard to copy ;)

Comment: Your HTML is invalid and your class name spelling is inconsistent. `$( ".dekstop .normal_p" )` isn't going to match anything, so the `console.log` will never be called, so it won't report `undefined` as you say. Please provide a reduced test case that actually demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Yeah, pretty much everything is wrong with your code, please at least try to make an effort.

Comment: `var attId   = $(this).parent(".level3_sub").attr('data-bookmark-flag');` what is this

Comment: `".dekstop"` ??? or `".desktop"` in `$( ".dekstop .normal_p" )`

Comment: level3_sub is not parent of that element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

".level3_sub" is the sibling of ".normal_p" , not the parent.

So, try this code

```
$( ".dekstop .normal_p" ).each(function( index ) {
     var attId   = $(this).siblings(".level3_sub").attr('data-bookmark-flag');
     console.log(attId);
     console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div class="desktop">
       <h2 class="level3_sub" data-bookmark-flag="3">Lorem ipsum dolor</h2>
       <p class='normal_p'> dfsdfsdfsdfsdf</p>
       <p class='normal_p'> dfsdfsdfsdfsdf</p>
 </div>

$( ".desktop .normal_p" ).each(function( index ) {

    var attId   = $(this).parent().children(".level3_sub").attr('data-bookmark-flag');
    console.log(attId);
});
```

Comment: There is still a typo in the selector. The class of the div is `desktop` not `dekstop`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $( ".dekstop .normal_p" ).each(function( index ) {

    var attId   = $(this).parent().find(".level3_sub").attr('data-bookmark-flag');

    console.log( attId   );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the class "desktop" in the same way you already did with "normal_p":

```
<div class="desktop">
```

And don't forget to close your second div.